# Finding indices of differences between corresponding elements of two lists

Tags: python

Say you have two lists of the same length:

`a=['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'w']`, 
`b=['x', 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'z']`

I wish to compare corresponding elements of both lists, and return a list of indices in which the two lists differ. In this case, it should return `[1, 5]`. The order of this list doesn't matter.

I know how to achieve this with a for loop, but are there any more efficient ways?

Comment: To know if is more or less efficient, you should show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'w']
b=['x', 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'z']

print( [idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(a, b)) if i != j] )
```

Prints:

```
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple list comprehension:

```
a=['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'w']
b=['x', 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'z']
print([i for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != b[i]])
```

Output

```
[1, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be useful to learn about `filter`:

```
>>> a = ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'w']
>>> b = ['x', 'w', 'y', 'x', 'z', 'z']
>>> f = [(ea[1] != eb[1]) for ea, eb in zip(enumerate(a), enumerate(b))]
>>> list(filter(lambda x : f[x], range(len(a))))
[1, 5]
```