# Find elements' indices with maximum difference between two lists

Tags: python, list

There are two lists

l1 = [1, 2.3, 1.4, 1.1]

l2 = [2.1, 0.9, 1.1, 3.2]

and I want to find the elements in the lists that have the maximum difference between the lists.

I.e.:

l1 = [**1**, 2.3, 1.4, 1.1] should return 0 for index 0 of the smallest number

l2 = [2.1, 0.9, 1.1, **3.2**] should return 3 for index 3 of the highest number

Comment: Good, the task is clear. What did you try and where exactly does it fail to provide the expected output?

Comment: `min(range(len(l1)), key=l1.__getitem__)` and `max(range(len(l2)), key=l2.__getitem__)`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: `l1 = [1, 2.3, 1.4, 1.1]
l2 = [2.1, 0.9, 1.1, 3.2]
result = [idx for idx, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(l1, l2)) if max(abs(i-j))]` based on [Andrej Kesely answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59742924/15658660) was my attempt. But it did fail. I did not want to include it, because I think it is misleading.

Comment: @MechanicPig: I want to base it on the **maximum difference**. In reality, I will not be able to give a prediction whether l1 or l2 contains the highest / smallest number. Nevertheless - thank you for the answer!

Comment: The maximum difference between values in the two lists is 3.2 - 0.9. Therefore the outputs should be 1 & 3

Comment: @LancelotduLac: You are right, I modified the question title.

Comment: max() will give you the biggest value of a _list_. max(abs(i-j)) can never work because abs(i-j) is a single value.

Comment: @Olli: Thank you for pointing this out. It was a poor attempt... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
l1 = [1, 2.3, 1.4, 1.1]
l2 = [2.1, 0.9, 1.1, 3.2]


def max_diff(l1, l2):
    min_l1 = min(l1)
    max_l1 = max(l1)
    min_l2 = min(l2)
    max_l2 = max(l2)
    max_diff1 = max_l2 - min_l1
    max_diff2 = max_l1 - min_l2
    if max_diff1 > max_diff2:
        return l1.index(min_l1), l2.index(max_l2), max_diff1
    else:
        return l1.index(max_l1), l2.index(min_l2), max_diff2


l1_index, l2_index, max_diff = max_diff(l1, l2)
print(l1_index, l2_index, max_diff)  # 0 3 2.2
```

Note that this computes the max difference and can return either the (min(l1), max(l2)) or (max(l1), min(l2)) depending on the items in the list.

Comment: This was the code I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quote from the original question "...I want to find the elements in the lists that have the maximum difference..." therefore the answer should be 1 & 3 based on the values 0.9 and 3.2 (which happen to be in the same list)

Comment: I believe he wants the min and max elements to be from separate lists. This can be seen from the line 
l1 = [1, 2.3, 1.4, 1.1] should return 0 for index 0 of the smallest number.
If min and max were among all the items, then he would've mentioned min as 0.9

Comment: @iR0ckY You are right. It is clear from the example and you helped me the right way. @ LancelotduLac I tried to make it a bit clearer, sorry for the confusing title.

Answer (score 1):

In case there are multiple results:

```
l1 = [1, 2.3, 3.2, 1]
l2 = [1, 1, 1.1, 3.2]


def find_all(list1, list2):
    def return_all(func, lst):
        return [pos for pos, val in enumerate(lst) if val == func(lst)]
    return [return_all(max, list1), return_all(min, list2)]


def output(res, order):
    print(f"max position list {order[0]}: {res[order[0] - 1]}")
    print(f"min position list {order[1]}: {res[order[1] - 1]}")


if max(l1) - min(l2) > max(l2) - min(l1):
    results = find_all(l1, l2)
    output(results, (1, 2))
elif max(l1) - min(l2) < max(l2) - min(l1):
    results = find_all(l2, l1)
    output(results[::-1], (2, 1))
else:
    results = find_all(l1, l2)
    output(results, (1, 2))
    print ('And:')
    results = find_all(l2, l1)
    output(results[::-1], (2, 1))
```

**output:**

```
    max position list 1: [2]
    min position list 2: [0, 1]
    And:
    max position list 2: [3]
    min position list 1: [0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more concise approach:

```
l1 = [1, 2.3, 1.4, 1.1]
l2 = [2.1, 0.9, 1.1, 3.2]

for k, v in {min: ['lo', l1], max: ['hi', l2]}.items():
    print(f'{v[0]}={k(range(len(v[1])), key=v[1].__getitem__)}')
```

**Output:**

```
lo=0
hi=3
```

Comment: Sadly, this only works when l1 < l2.

Comment: @FabianPascher You have previously said that you want to compare the min from l1 with max from l2 (review your comments). If both lists were considered together then the answer would be 1 & 3 because both the min and max values are in l2. My answer is therefore aligned perfectly with your stated requirements